# Send JSON data to Server via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, post, postman

I've a service to consume, the details of the service are as follows.

```
POST /API/v02/JsonWs.svc/json/V02 HTTP/1.1 [OR] POST /API/Public/v02/JsonWs.svc/json/V02 HTTP/1.1
 Host: dev.domain.us
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie: LogicAuth=3821F201156EA833......; path=/; HttpOnly

{"Header":{"Procedure":"Family_Insert"},"Body":{"EmailAddress":"email22222@domain.net","Password":"test14","IdPhoneNumber":3051234567,"Address":{"Line1":"1234 Avenue","Line2":"Suite 900","City":"Coral","ZipCode":"33327","State":{"IdState":10}},"TimeZone":{"IdTimeZone":-5},"User":{"IdGender":1,"NameFirst":"Tom","NameMiddle":"Larry","NameLast":"Lewis","DateBirth":"10-21-1978","ClubName":"ABC","Communities":[1,2],"UserConnectTypes":[3,4]}}}
```

The javascript code to initiate from:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/json-handler");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

In your answer, you don't have to use all variables, I just need some help to get me going...

Edit:
Please specify the next steps of how to send json data to the server after I set the request headers in `xmlhttp`. I'm not sure what URL to send data to the above service.

On the side can someone tell me how to test the above service in chrome postman?

Comment: What is your question exactly? I don't see a question.

Comment: edited to made it clear, what's the next step, how to encode json data for the server,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.send('{"Header":{"Procedure".......');
```

Basically, you need to construct a string of your JSON, and call `xmlhttp.send(jsonStr)`.

One way to create that JSON string is like this:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
  Header: {
    Procedure: 'Family_Insert'
  },
  Body: ....
});
```

Also, you seem to be using the wrong address. Complete sample:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://dev.domain.us/API/v02/JsonWs.svc/json/V02');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
   Header: {
      Procedure: 'Family_Insert'
   },
   Body: ....
});
xhr.send(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Thanks Alxandar, also I'm not sure where to send data to? can you please figure it out from the headers I sent you? Is it going to be dev.domain.us/api/V02/JsonWs.svc/json/V02 or what? Basically what's the end point?

Comment: and what is this cooking thing? Cookie: LogicAuth=3821F201156EA833......; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: Cookie header is just as it sounds, cookies. Although, I don't think you **can** set them in an XHR, you can always try.

Comment: thanks I'm seeing the edits, any help with the chrome extension? I selected a post request, with body as Raw and selected JSON from the type next to it but getting some error forms, I posted the json string as it is in the body

Comment: I have no idea how to do chrome extensions.

Comment: no sorry, I mean there's a chrome extension available called Postman to test services, are you familiar with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61919/discussion-between-user2727195-and-alxandr).

Comment: I received this response. do you think it has to do something with the cookie logic auth code {
    "Message": "Authentication failed.",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}